# Express.js routing between files

Tags: node.js, express

i have 3 files: server.js, bookhandler.js, books.js

i assume that there will be requests like: /book/name, /book/type, /book etc.
according to the first field in the url, which is book(it can also be video and magazine),i want my server.js to direct me to the bookhandler.js file with the post parameters. i only want a function here which i can validate the parameters. and if parameters are valid, i want to pass the parameters to my books.js file which i can make my post request with those valid parameters.if the first field of url is video, it should direct me to videohandler etc.

server.js

```
app.use('/book', require('./bookhandler').middleware);
```

this is what i did so far, and it directs me to the bookhandler file, but i dont know how to get parameters and validate inside a function

EDİT:

> ```
> bookhandler.js
> ```

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

module.exports.middleware = function (req, res) {

    var id = req.body.id;

    if(id.length==5) {
        app.use('/id', require('../book').middleware));
    }
};
```

> ```
> book.js
> ```

```
app.post('/id' , function (req, res) {

});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't direct execution to a file, but to a function.  Files are just a way of organizing functions or any type of code.

Based on this example you gave, I assume that `bookhandler.js` exports a function named `middleware` in its module.exports object.  That function, when called, will be passed a reference to the request and response objects.  The request object has the parameters in it.

For example:

```
bookhandler.js:

module.exports.middleware = function (req, res) {
    var bookId = req.params.bookId;
    // do something with bookId
};
```

[Edit based on latest update of question]

You are over-riding module.exports.  After setting module.exports.middleware to a valid function, you replace module.exports in its entirety with a reference to app.

Remove this line and your problem should be solved.

```
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: thats great, but lets assume that i post to /books/id. with your function it perfectly passes the parameter to handler, but how can i pass it to book.js and make a app.post to /books/id with the parameteres. thank you so much!

Comment: Same thing.  Files are irrelevant.  The request routing is based on function calls, whatever files they may live in.

Comment: so how can i call app.post('/init' , function (req, res) {}); from middleware

Comment: Exactly the way you did it!

Comment: yes but it is in a different file, how do i pass the bookid paramater and call the post from bookhandler.js, an example would really be great thank you !

Comment: The example code in your question would do it.  app.post('/book', require('bookhandler.js').middleware);

Comment: like you said, i added the function to bookhandler.js, and i validate the id and when its valid i added this app.use('/id', require('../book').middleware);' but it didnt work

Comment: "but it didnt work" - what goes wrong?  I won't edit my answer yet because I don't have anything to add to it yet.